# PostgreSQL: how can I Alter table by setting a column of the selected rows to be increasing integers?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table named `issue` with thousands of rows:

| id | status | listPosition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | New | 0 |
| 44 | New | 0 |
| 45 | New | 0 |
| 46 | Accepted | 0 |
| 51 | Accepted | 1 |
| 54 | Accepted | 0 |
| 66 | processing | 0 |
| 68 | processing | 0 |

I want to select all rows whose `status` is a specific value, like `New`, and update the `listPosition` value such that they are in increasing indexes, like 1, 2, 3, ....

the result should be like :

| id | status | listPosition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | New | 1 |
| 44 | New | 2 |
| 45 | New | 3 |
| 46 | Accepted | 1 |
| 51 | Accepted | 2 |
| 54 | Accepted | 3 |
| 66 | processing | 1 |
| 68 | processing | 2 |

How can I do that in PostgreSql?

I tried:

```
UPDATE issue SET listPosition= 'dummy.listPosition'
FROM  
(
  SELECT id, row_number() over (partition by status order by id) AS "listPosition" FROM issue
) AS dummy
WHERE issue.id= 'dummy.id';
```

and it gives this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "dummy.id"
LINE 6: WHERE issue.id= 'dummy.id';
```

How did it fail?

I tried both:  (don't worry about the `dstOrgId` thing)

```
UPDATE issue SET listPosition= "dummy.listPosition"
FROM  
(
  SELECT id, row_number() over (partition by "dstOrgId", status order by id) AS "listPosition" FROM issue order by id
) AS dummy
WHERE issue.id = dummy.id;



WITH dummy AS
(
  SELECT id, row_number() over (partition by "dstOrgId", status order by id) AS "listPosition" FROM issue order by id
) 
UPDATE issue set listPosition = "dummy.listPosition"
FROM dummy
WHERE issue.id = dummy.id;
```

They all gives error:

```
ERROR:  column "dummy.listPosition" does not exist
LINE 5: UPDATE issue set listPosition = "dummy.listPosition"
```

Why on earth does it not exist???  PostgreSQL syntax is so freaking strange, since it asks me to change `set listPosition = dummy.listPosition` to `set listPosition = "dummy.listPosition"`, and complains that column does not exist.

what????

---

I have finally got the working command through trial and error:

```
UPDATE issue SET "listPosition"= dummy."listPosition"
FROM  
(
  SELECT id, row_number() over (partition by "dstOrgId", status order by id) AS "listPosition" FROM issue order by id
) AS dummy
WHERE issue.id = dummy.id;
```

what is the significance of double quote and the difference between single quote and double quote in PostgreSQL anyways?

Comment: try  `UPDATE issue SET listPosition= dummy."listPosition"`

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, there is no column `"dummy.listPosition"` as double quoting the whole thing turns it into a single identifier instead of what you wanted which was `"dummy"."listPosition"`. The CTE 'table' "dummy" and the 'table' column "listPosition". See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: @jian  this is not enough though, the finally working code is `SET "listPosition"= dummy."listPosition"`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using [row_number](https://postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

```
select   id
        ,status
        ,row_number() over (partition by status order by id) as listPosition
from     t 
order by id, status
```

| id | status | listposition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | New | 1 |
| 44 | New | 2 |
| 45 | New | 3 |
| 46 | Accepted | 1 |
| 51 | Accepted | 2 |
| 54 | Accepted | 3 |
| 66 | processing | 1 |
| 68 | processing | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=76eeca432474ab83df123a3c630b781b&hide=1)

Comment: this only shows the result, but does not actually change the column value though.

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: sorry, busy day. I'll get to it by tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got the working command through trial and error:

```
UPDATE issue SET "listPosition"= dummy."listPosition"
FROM  
(
  SELECT id, row_number() over (partition by "dstOrgId", status order by id) AS "listPosition" FROM issue order by id
) AS dummy
WHERE issue.id = dummy.id;
```